# Modifying AucTeX bracket indentation locally

Tags: indentation, auctex, balanced-parentheses

I am currently using songs package, which via some TeX trickery uses escaped brackets to mark chords (for example `\[G]` is G-major, while `\[a]` is a-minor). This causes problems with indentation, for example this is how the following snippet gets indented (every `\[` introduces new indent level):

```latex
\begin{song}
  \begin{verse}
    \[G]This is \[D]some \[A]guitar song
          \[G]annotated with \[D]the chords
              to \[e]make playing ea\[H7]sier.
  \end{verse}
\end{song}
```

while of course I would like to get:

```latex
\begin{song}
  \begin{verse}
    \[G]This is \[D]some \[A]guitar song
    \[G]annotated with \[D]the chords
    to \[e]make playing ea\[H7]sier.
  \end{verse}
\end{song}
```

I managed to resolve this by removing bracket indentation completely:

```el
(setq LaTeX-begin-regexp "begin\\b")      ; Default is begin\\b\\|\\[
(setq LaTeX-end-regexp "end\\b")          ; Default is end\\b\\|\\]
```

but this impacts also my various other uses of `\[`, including math…

So, the question is, whether it is possible to disable *indenting* behaviour of bracket just inside specific environment (`song`), while leaving it unchanged everywhere else.

If impossible, what is the easiest/recommended way to change `LaTeX-begin-regex` and `LaTeX-end-regexp` just for specific files instead of customizing it globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can advise `LaTeX-indent-level-count`

```lisp
(defadvice LaTeX-indent-level-count
    (around advice-LaTeX-indent-level-count activate)
  (let ((LaTeX-begin-regexp
     (if (equal (LaTeX-current-environment) "verse")
         "begin\\b"
       "begin\\b\\|\\["))
    (LaTeX-end-regexp
     (if (equal (LaTeX-current-environment) "verse")
         "end\\b"
       "end\\b\\|\\]")))
    ad-do-it))
```

This will set `LaTeX-begin-regexp` to `"begin\\b"` within `verse` environment and to `"begin\\b\\|\\["` otherwise, the same for `LaTeX-end-regexp`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I slightly fixed the function to accomodate more environments, will post it as next answer.
Question: could this be improved to handle indirect cases (like \begin{verse}\begin{somethelse}...)

Comment: `LaTeX-current-environment` can take an optional argument with the number of the outer environment to check. For small changes you can also edit this answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Slightly fixed function, to accomodate different wrapping environments

```
 (defadvice LaTeX-indent-level-count
      (around advice-LaTeX-indent-level-count activate)
    (let* ((dont-indent-bracket (member (LaTeX-current-environment)
                                        '("song" "verse" "chorus")))
           (LaTeX-begin-regexp (if dont-indent-bracket
                                   "begin\\b"
                                 "begin\\b\\|\\["))
           (LaTeX-end-regexp (if dont-indent-bracket
                                 "end\\b"
                               "end\\b\\|\\]")))
      ad-do-it))
```